# How do I communicate between Javascript and Flex?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, air

I have a windowed Flex application *(AIR)* that uses an HTML file for the UI, but I have some Flex code that needs to be executed when the page is loaded.

I have imported the HTML interface into the app using the **< mx:HTML /> tag**. The Adobe help at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_5.html shows a way to communicate between javascript and flex, but only if you are using an external HTML file in a browser, and not in a windowed app.

So my question is this: how do I make a call to a flex method from javascript that will return data in a windowed/*AIR* app?

Any help will be appreciated as I am very new to flex/flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to be looking at is the documentation for the HTMLLoader Class, such as this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ed4.html .

Comment: The final solution was a bit tedious, but it's basis was found on this link, so I shall mark it as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It should also work in windowed app. Using ExternalInterface

Flex -> js

```
ExternalInterface.call("jsFunction", {par:value});
```

js -> Flex

```
flashObject = document.getElementById(flashid);

if( flashObject ) {
    flashObject.flexMethod("par");
} else {
    alert('Error! could not get flash object');
}
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_4.html

Comment: Down voting, because obviously WindowedApplication can't be embedded in an HTML page, and so clearly CANNOT invoke ExternalInterface, as noted by the original poster.

Comment: Ok, sorry, wasn't clear about term "windowed application" - thought it could be something like an iframe :/ !!!